# SPSS select random cases while having a condition on a variable

Tags: spss

I would like to select random cases from a group of cases that have a value of 1 on one of the variables. It only seems possible to select random cases from the total subset, and not with a condition.

This is a simple example of my dataset:

```
case 1. value  0
case 2. value  1
case 3. value  0
case 4. value  1
case 5. value  1
case 6. value  1
case 7. value  0
```

So, I would like to draw random cases (50%) from those cases that have a value of 1 for the variable category. That would leave case 1, 3 and 7 out of the random selection.

An option would be to transfer those cases with the value of 1 to another database and then select random cases. However, I would like to keep all the cases in the database.

Does anyone know if this is possible in SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of talking you through how to achieve this, if you step through the example below it should provide sufficient information how to do this:

```
DATA LIST FREE / X1 TO X3 D1.
BEGIN DATA
1 2 3 0
4 5 6 1
7 8 9 1
1 2 3 0
4 5 6 1
7 8 9 1
1 2 3 0
4 5 6 1
7 8 9 1
1 2 3 1
4 5 6 1
7 8 9 0
1 2 3 1
4 5 6 1
7 8 9 0
END DATA.
DATASET NAME DS1.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=D1 /CountN=N.
COMPUTE Rand=RV.UNIFORM(0,1).
RANK Rand BY D1.
COMPUTE FILTER=D1=1 and RRand<=(CountN/2).
SORT CASES BY D1 Rand.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a simple compute like
compute keep = value EQ 1 and rv.uniform(0,1) GE .5.
FILTER BY keep.  (if retaining all the cases in the dataset but using only the keep cases in procedures), or
SELECT IF . to delete the unselected cases.

Comment: I thought of this initially only to then realise you may not alway randomly generate to select 50% of the cases.

Comment: The formula will do 50% of the selected cases subject to random variation.  If it needs to be exactly 50%, other measures are required.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible. I assume that you have solved this issue but maybe it will be useful for someone else. It's quite simple. First, you select all cases that have a value of 1 (or any required values) in '**Select cases**' '**If condition is satisfied**' and then in '**Output**' section you have to chose '**Copy selected cases to a new dataset**', and save it as a new dataset. Now, you can make a split test (Draw a random sample of cases) in a new dataset with required parameters.